# Is, "$|f_n|\leq g$ eventually", sufficient for dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Dominated Convergence Theorem: If $(f_n:n\geq 1)$ is a sequence of measurable functions and there exists a Lebesgue integrable function $g$ such that 
$|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n\geq 1$, then $\lim\int f_n\,d\mu=\int \lim f_n\,d\mu$.

My question: If we relax the hypothesis "$|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n\geq 1$" to 
"$|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n\geq N$", where $N$ is some positive integer, does the conclusion still hold?

Comment: Yes. Eventual behaviour is all that matters for sequences.

Comment: Yes, if all $f_n$ are integrable. Otherwise you need to start the sequence at $N.$

Comment: In this case we would still say $\int f_n\,d\mu\to \int f$? Since even if say the first $k$ integrals are infinity eventually they would tend to the real number $\int f$?

Comment: Yes, simple re-index your sequence of functions to start from $N+1$